# How to listen to radio flash, a media player?

Tags: internet-radio, audacious

I would like to hear radio from streaming flash, eg http://www.los40principales.com.ar/player/player.htm .  I can hear it from firefox, but I wonder if it is possible to listen to the radio in audacious through a plugin or something. Greetings and thanks in advance

i have audacious 3.3.1 ubuntu 12.04 64 bits

Answer (score -2):

You need flash player to play. You might have flash but the current version of flash (flash 11) have various issues. You need to downgrade flash to a previous verion.

Here is what you can do: (Im assuming you have flash 11 and firefox 14.0.1):

```
Download this file : http://www.ziddu.com/download/20225702/libflashplayer.zip.html

Create a folder "plugins" under "/home/YOUR-USER-NAME/.mozilla/firefox/"

Like this:  /home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins

Extract the zip and copy the downloaded "libflashplayer.so" to "/home/leopard/.mozilla/firefox/plugins"

Open nautilus as Admin. Go to "/usr/lib/adobe-flashplugin". Delete the "libflashplayer.so" there.

Copy the extracted "libflashplayer.so" there.

Restart firefox.
```

[image]

Comment: who are ziddu.com and why should the OP and other users trust them with important stuff like flash?

Comment: I can play the radio in firefox now, I would play this type of radio that have flash streaming, without firefox, audacious or reproduce in mplayer

Comment: i meant no starting firefox for online radio ( with flash streaming) just play the radio on a media player sorry for my bad english