# How do I listen to radio hidden in flash players in audacious?

Tags: flash, streaming, internet-radio, audacious

This question has [been asked before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182022/how-to-listen-to-radio-flash-a-media-player) but was misunderstood. Just like the asker in the other thread, my goal is *not* to install flash in my browser so I can hear flash-based radio in the browser. My goal is to extract the real media url so I can listen to that radio in players like audacious.

To back this up with an example: http://www.boomerradio.com/ How do I listen to these stations on audacious?

I've tried looking in etherape and in the source of the page to find the actual streaming url, but I think they hide it deliberately.

Comment: You need a plugin for your browser that allows to analyze the objects on a web page. I had success with abusing AdBlock(plus).

Comment: I've tried that, with the result that I see an url with a proprietary adobe format rtmp:                       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol                               The url looks like this: rtmp://boomerradio-wowza.streamguys.com:80    This url can't be understood. What surprises me, the ALSA plug in container can forward the music to the speakers, so how is this rtmp url translated. Confusing...

Answer (score 1):

I can only answer for BoomerRadio.com in particular - they've added a page with "Internet Radio Device Links" that lists URLs that can be plugged in to various media players.

Link to that page: http://www.boomerradio.com/boomerfaq.htm

I imagined you have already used a URL sniffer/snooper to get the "Wowza" URL mentioned in your original reply.

Answer (score 0):

Jabba Laci made [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/144888/wordpress/20130606-digitally-imported-station-urls/extract.py.txt) script to extract station URLs. I don't understand it (if you do please explain it) but he used to get di.fm urls seen [here](https://ubuntuincident.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/digitally-imported-station-urls/).

Answer (score 0):

Install [Wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) (*wireshark* in the repositories), and then follow the [process for finding the radio stream URL](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/13425/streaming-url):

1. Close all other applications, except the browser.
2. Close all tabs in the browser, except the one that loads the web radio page.
3. Capture the whole traffic of your system, while you listen to the radio stream. **HINT**: You must start the capture before you click on the "Play" button/link. Don't use any capture filter!
4. Look at the TCP statistics (`Statistics -> Conversation List -> TCP`).
5. Sort the out for "Bytes" or "Packets".
6. The connection with the most Bytes/Packets is most certainly the audio stream.
7. Click on that connection and then click on "Follow Stream".
8. At the beginning of the TCP connection, you should see the URL (if it was streamed via HTTP).

You should then be able to play the stream via [Rhythmbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhythmbox) or other players.